# Como puedo definir una variable en Python usando if?

Tags: python, if

Lo que basicamente quiero hacer seria:
Establecer a partir de los input un valor max y otro minimo pero no se como hacerlo.

```
if lado1>lado2 and lado3:
...     print("A=lado1")
... 
 if lado2>lado1 and lado3:
...     print("A=lado2")
... 
if lado3>lado1 and lado2:
...     print("A=lado3")
```

Como puedo a partir de los if de arriba crear esa variable?Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Ivan, ¿Por qué no usas simplemente las funciones `min` y `max`?: `maximo, minimo = max(lado1, lado2, lado3), min(lado1, lado2, lado3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más adecuado sería después de cada if, utilizar: 
`A = ladoQueQuieras` y separar los ifs con `else` para que no se ejecuten todos innecesariamente. Al final, y fuera de los ifs, usas `print(A)`.

Algo así como:

```
if lado1>lado2 and lado1>lado3:
...     A=lado1
... 
elif lado2>lado1 and lado2>lado3:
...     A=lado2
... 
else
...     A=lado3
...
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

pues básicamente tendrías que primero hacer dicha entrada, que seria

> lado1=int(input())
>   lado2=int(input())
>   lado3=int(input())

Y luego como dice @FJSevilla pues tendrías que con la función ***max*** sacar los máximos y los mínimos con la función ***min*** entonces estaría de la siguiente forma:

> Máximo=max(lado1,lado2,lado3)  Mínimo=min(lado1,lado2,lado3)

Y python te retorna el máximo y mínimo.

Tambien se podría una forma mas extensa que seria con condicionales evaluando todos los casos, entonces sería:

```
If lado1>lado2 and lado2>lado3:
     Print('el máximo es', lado1,'y el mínimo es',lado3 )

elif lado1>lado3 and lado3>lado2:
     Print('el maximo es ',lado1,'el mínimo es ', lado3)
```

Y así sucesivamente....